# Store image into windows path using a URL and MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

On an `INSERT INTO` MS SQL 2104 I would like to use an image reference in the inserted data e.g.

```
ProductImage = https://some.site/products/RedVan.jpg
```

and check to see if this image exists on the local server in a particular directory, e.g. `D:\customers\CustomerA\Images`.

If the image is not found in the directory, I would like to download the image using the URL to the folder directory.

Can this be done in an `SQL AFTER INSERT` Trigger?

Comment: Yes, it can be done (by abusing `xp_cmdshell`). No, you shouldn't be doing it. Move this logic to your client. SQL Server is a database engine and should not be used to download random stuff from the internet.

Comment: The 'client' is running on another server and is simply inserting data into the MS SQL database.

Comment: [`FILESTREAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server) gives you access to files through SQL Server, but downloading stuff from SQL Server itself would still be a bad idea, from both a scaling and reliability perspective. Even if all the clients can't do that either, a dedicated separate server for handling the files would still be a better idea.

Comment: Thanks, we need the jpg images stored in a folder for a subsequent process.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this. But you don't understand  if there are 2 different images with same name. If image name is constant and only you will use this app maybe don't problem it. I think you have to  find "how can you understand if image exist on server" Like name, byte, date... You have to compare uploaded image with images on own server.

Your sql code : "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Images WHERE ImageName=@ImageName) BEGIN insert into  Images () values () END"

This code: if there is "a.jpg" on server don't insert it if there isn't insert it.

Comment: The image name will always be constant from the URL.  We perform a check to see if the image exists but we're currently not moving the file into the directory if the filename is not already in the directory.

Comment: ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FileExists](filename varchar(512))

RETURNS varchar(512)

AS

BEGIN
declare Path varchar(512)
 select Path = 'D:\Customers\CustomerA\Images\'

 declare i int

 declare File varchar(1024)
 select File = Path + FileName

 declare result varchar(512) 
 exec master..xp_fileexist File, i out
 if i = 1
  select result = filename
 else
  select result = 'NoImage.jpg'
 RETURN result
END;